# Digital elevation model (DEM) with API

Tags: api, dictionary

I need to add DEM to my project (map based on the Qt but it isn't matter). Currently I use the google map using their API (http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs ...).
Which services can provide DEM data? For example I do HTTP request with coordinates and zoom and it responses me picture.
Thanks))